# Regular Expression using character “-” in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I use VS 2012 and RegExp in C#.
I have an regular expression like this:

```
^CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ([\w]+).([\w]+) IS
```

I read `contents` from a file.

I have troubles with character `-`

`Test_A_B` is OK.
`Test-A_B` is **KO**.

I tried using `Regex.Escape` but it's still wrong.

Unit test code:

```
var pattern1 = @"^CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ([\w]+).([\w]+) IS";
var regexPackage = new Regex(pattern1);

var contents = @"CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ZZZ.Test_A_B IS";
match1 = regexPackage.Match(contents);
Assert.IsTrue(match1.Success);
Assert.AreNotEqual(0, match1.Groups.Count);
Assert.AreEqual("Test_A_B", match1.Groups[2].Value);

contents = @"CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE ZZZ.Test-A_B IS";
//contents = Regex.Escape(contents);
match1 = regexPackage.Match(contents);
Assert.IsTrue(match1.Success); <===== FAILS
Assert.AreNotEqual(0, match1.Groups.Count);
Assert.AreEqual("Test-A_B", match1.Groups[2].Value);
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\w` includes alphanumeric characters as well as the underscore. It doesn't include the dash.

Simply replace `[\w]+` in your regex with `[-\w]+` to include the dash.

As a side note, the dash has a special meaning in character classes. It either needs to be first in the class, or last, or be escaped with a backslash.